# Extract output from scipy optimise

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, scipy, minimize

After minimising a two parameter function in Python using the Powell algorithm, I am left with the following output:

```
fun: -3.5839582049322310
maxcv: 0.0
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nfev: 98
status: 1
success: True
   x: array([ 1.9116445888705806,  3.7094985019795996])
```

I wish to extract the two optimised parameters in x to then be carried through to another part of the script. Is there a way to automate the extraction of these numbers without having to manually enter them in the script? I have looked in the `scipy` documentation but have not found anything on how to access the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the code you use to calculate your result, now I can only guess what you did.

I assume your code looks like:

```
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, f0, method='Powell')
```

This [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) returns an [optimizeResult](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html) object. To get the actual result of your optimization you need to call

```
print(res.x)
```

The type of `res.x` is a numpy.ndarray. If you want to proceed only if your calculation was successful, then you can do something like

```
if res.success:
    print('success, the results are')
    print(res.x)
```

Comment: Of course! So simple, can't believe I didn't think of that, print res.x works